# on clicking user redirect to login page if signed in

Tags: php, redirect, onclick

i want to make a link where user click will go to the login page if they have not signed into thier account otherwise to will able to access the page they want

```
<li><?php session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != ''))
{
    //header ("Location: login.php");
    echo("<script>alert('login to see this page');</script>");
}
else 
    echo ('<a href="ask-expert.php">')?>Ask A Export</a></li>
```

I had the snippet above tried to do it myself but failed it just alert (purposely given) and my text of the link get hidden. Also if i used header not alert it auto redirect to login but i want that with click! How can it be possible?

Comment: Your `if` logic doesn't make sense: try `if (!(isset($_SESSION['login'])) || $_SESSION['login'] == '') {
`

Comment: so you want a js alert that on ok redirect to the login page?

Comment: <li>

<?php session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
echo("<script>alert('login to see this page');</script>");
?>

<a href="login.php">Ask to an Expert</a>

<?php 
} ?>
</li>

Comment: sense is that if user click on the link php will check the user login status according to which it will navigate. if already logged in then the page url otherwise to the login page!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't send data before starting the session (the `<li>` tag).

Sessions uses cookies and cookies are set in HTTP headers. The server cannot add headers if content has already been sent.

You will have the same probleme with the `header()` function by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Call javascript function while onClick. Then redirect to login page using javascript,

`document.location`

Or

simply use anchor tag for that link/button

```
<a href="login.php">Ask to an Expert</a>
```